# @QueryParam does not set value

Tags: web-services, jax-rs

I have a web-service as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("/push")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String push(@QueryParam("comment") String comment,
                   @QueryParam("type") String type){
     // do something
}
```

and my request body is:

```
{
    "comment" : "comment1",
    "type" : "type1"
}
```

My web-service is called when appropriate post request is made but parameters `comment` and `type` has `null` value. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing query Parameter with Post request payload.

[@QueryParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html)
Query parameters are extracted from the request URI query parameters and are specified by using the javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation in the method parameter arguments.

Query parameters are optional if you dont set them they will be set to null.

if you want to keep 'comment & type' as query parameter you should pass them as follows:

```
http://<HOST:port>/push?comment=comment1&type=type1
```

The Post method **Payload** is instead what you will send along with your POST request.

In your case you are passing 'comment' and 'type' as payload but it is not mapped to anything.

if you want to receive your payload, get mapped to an object, you should do a little change.

First, create a class annotated with @XmlRootElement

```
@XmlRootElement    
class MyMessage{
String comment;
String type;
//add getter and setter
}
```

and your rest API entry point will look like this :

```
@POST
@Path("/push")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String push(MyMessage message){
     String comment = message.getComment()
     String type = message.getType()
     // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is that possible to use multiple arguments in the second method you provided?

Comment: short answer: nop!
What you could do is: accept an object the contains all the parameters you need (including the second parameter you want to add)  OR accept list of objects something like : List<MyMessage >. Obliviously you will need to adapt the JSON payload accordingly.